# Get Sharepoint current userKey with Javascript

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, spuser

I have been trying to get current users key value with many different ways, but none of them has worked as I wanted.
I need to get current SPUser key (i:0#.w|dev\user) to compare with the key on table.

Closest thing I have at the moment is [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20981226/sharepoint-2013-get-current-user-javascript) But the problem there is, that it gets users Id and can't get key. Or maybe I missed something, but tried it many ways.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve that with following example: [passing variable values from c# to javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20849272/passing-variable-values-from-c-sharp-to-javascript) using a little C# code.